# How to prevent certain fields based on another fields value with JSON Schema validator

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Depending on the salaryRange the user selects I need to validate differently by requiring some fields and rejecting others. I feel like its a combination of allOf and not but I can't seem to quite get it.

**Scenario #1**

User selects salaryRange(Hourly)

- Require hourlyRate
- Prevent the submission of fields feeOne and feeTwo

**Scenario #2**

User selects salaryRange(0-50k OR 50-100k)

- Require feeOne and feeTwo
- Prevent the submission of field hourlyRate

Here is my schema

```
{
  "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$id": "http://mysite/schemas/job.json#",
  "title": "Job",
  "description": "Create job",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": { "type": "string" },
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "salaryRange": { "enum": ["0-50k", "50-100k", "100-150k", "150-200k", "200-300k", "300k+", "nonExempt", "Hourly"] },  
    "hourlyRate": { 
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 300 
    },
    "feeOne": { 
      "type": "number", 
      "minimum": 0 
    },
    "feeTwo": { 
      "type": "number", 
      "minimum": 0 
    }
  }    ,
  "additionalProperties": false,  
  "required": [
    "title", 
    "description", 
    "salaryRange"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `oneOf` and `not` `required` to model all possible combinations.

Here is an example in js:
https://runkit.com/embed/cf8cra1mwvx3/

```
{
  "schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "$id": "http://mysite/schemas/job.json#",
  "title": "Job",
  "description": "Create job",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "title": { "type": "string" },
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "salaryRange": { "enum": ["0-50k", "50-100k", "100-150k", "150-200k", "200-300k", "300k+", "nonExempt", "Hourly"] },  
    "hourlyRate": { 
      "type": "number",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 300 
    },
    "feeOne": { 
      "type": "number", 
      "minimum": 0 
    },
    "feeTwo": { 
      "type": "number", 
      "minimum": 0 
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
        "description": "Disallow fees for hourly salary",
        "properties": {
            "salaryRange": { "enum": ["Hourly"] }
        },
        "required": ["hourlyRate"],
        "allOf": [
            {"not":{"required":["feeOne"]}},
            {"not":{"required":["feeTwo"]}}
        ]
    },
    {
        "description": "Disallow hourly rate for 0-50k, 50-100k salaries",
        "properties": {
            "salaryRange": { "enum": ["0-50k", "50-100k"] }
        },
        "required": ["feeOne", "feeTwo"],
        "not":{"required":["hourlyRate"]}
    },
    {
        "description": "Allow other cases",
         "properties": {
            "salaryRange": { "not" : {"enum": ["Hourly", "0-50k", "50-100k"] } }
        }
    }
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,  
  "required": [
    "title", 
    "description", 
    "salaryRange"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is awesome - worked perfect thank you for your help!